# classes not being added in React using className

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React on the fly for a project and am having trouble adding classes to already existing components. I have checked other SO threads and looked through tutorials on the react site - it looks like I am doing it correctly with the className but it is not working. For example, in my Event.js:

```js
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <article>
          <div className="row">
            { this.drawOrderError() }
            <div className="large-4 columns event-img-div">
              <img src={ this.props.image }/>
            </div>
            <div className="large-8 columns event-right-column">
              { this.state.showCreditCard ? this.drawCreditCard() : this.drawTicketing() }
              <br />
              <div className="event-detail">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="large-12 column">
                    <span className="ticket-column-headings">Event Details</span>
                    <p className="event-details">{this.props.description}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
        { this.drawOrderSummaryOverlay() }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have added the class `event-img-div` - but when I go to the browser I do not see it added in console, and cannot apply styles to that class. What am I doing wrong? Can provide more code if needed.

I am changing the files in a local directory and running on local host, using gulp to start the server.

Comment: Is other stuff changing? if you put some random text next to the img tag does it display?

Comment: i just checked and it is not. i added some text below the div, it did not show. Then I tried wrapping it in a div and it did not show as well.

Comment: it there something i should be doing to make it recompile? or is it possible i am working in the wrong file? this is the file i was pointed to by the creator of the project to modify classes, etc. He warned me that adding classes would be tricky - however according to the tutorials and docs it seems it shouldn't. what am i missing here?

Comment: There's nothing tricky about adding classes, that's a ridiculous thing to say. Without knowing more about your project this could be any number of reasons, from not re-compiling, to wrong files etc... are you changing files in a local dir and running on localhost? how are you starting the server? etc etc add as many of those details into your original question and maybe we can help

Comment: I updated my question to add more details, i am changing the files in a local directory and running on local host, using gulp to start the server. I have restarted the server, but that has not helped. I believe it is not recompiling. I am not really sure what else to add so please let me know any other factors that I should outline.